# Pure CSS static starfield

Tags: css

I would like to know how to create a star field using only CSS where the stars do not move.  I have found some examples of animated star fields but I don't want the animation portion.  Please help me understand how this type of static background could be created without using image files.

Comment: Why do I get an immediate downvote...

Comment: I want a spaceship! But seriously, this question is lacking effort and understanding. Where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: No detail on what you want to achieve, no clear direction, you havent even tried to ask the right question.

Comment: Probably because your question is short, shows no demonstration of effort, and seems to purposely discount the usual solutions that might be the best or only possibilities...

Comment: Probably because your question is way too broad and you have not posted the code you currently have. SO is not a 'do my homework' site

Comment: In all seriousness, just google search for `css starfield` and see what you get...

Comment: @abiessu I couldn't find one that didn't move.

Comment: @snuggles08: that's a good start then.  Did you try to modify a moving one to see if you could get one that is stationary?

Comment: @abiessu No, I didn't.

Comment: @snuggles08: I don't think that edit will help much in terms of getting interest in answering your question.  Things like "here's what I tried, but these problems arose" would help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an exercise in "let's see what happens if..." the following code was directly stolen from [here](http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/zqcEd) and modified slightly to be static.  The result is predictable:  a basic, repetitive star field.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Testing a starfield</title>
  <style>
#space, .stars {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.stars {
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 30px, #eee, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 40px 70px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 50px 160px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 90px 40px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 130px 80px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(2px 2px at 160px 120px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="space">
   <div class="stars"></div>
   <div class="stars"></div>
   <div class="stars"></div>
   <div class="stars"></div>
   <div class="stars"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, the functional part of this CSS is building up the `background-image` in pieces made up of `radial-gradient` results.