# How to use an image placeholder while images load in a responsive grid?

Tags: css, image, placeholder

Using a responsive fluid grid and images are 800px x 500px

Problem: When images load, the footer as it the top and is pushed down while the images are loading in.

Setup: Using a div for the images and div for the footer.

Goal: To have the footer always remain in the correct position, not trying to put it in an absolute spot, just looking to have the images spacing accounted for.

Ideas: Perhaps use a transparent png at 800x500 so it loads first before the images.

Concerns: Creating a div placeholder at 800x500 might not work as these images are responsive in a fluid grid so they'll never actually be at that size unless the viewer has a huge monitor..

**Final result when images loaded:**
[image: 01]

**Current issue:**
[image: 02]

**Goal for images to load:**
[image: 03]

Comment: You could create a transparent image in CSS for loading purposes, then replace the transparent image references in the `onLoad` callbacks...

Comment: Thanks @abiessu could you point me in the right direction on how to execute this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663598/2592931 is an answer I put together talking about a basic way to create an image in CSS.  I'm sure there's a way to make one transparent as well.

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea what this means lol

Answer (score 12):

When I know the aspect ratio for something is going to stay the same no matter what the width of the elements/screen is, I do something like this:

```
.image-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.333%;
    position: relative;
}
.image-holder:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 62.5%;
}
.image-holder img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/serv0m8o/1/

I wrap each image in a `div` with a class of `image-holder` (which is styled to give you the 3 per row pattern that you illustrated) and make sure it is `position: relative;`

I then style the `:before` pseudo-element of that `div` to be the proper height of the aspect ratio that is needed. Padding in CSS is an intrinsic property, which means it is based on the width of the element, allowing you to assign a percentage which reflects the ratio. You specified 800x500 images, so `(500/800*100) = 62.5%` as my `padding-top`

Then, you can absolutely position your image to fill the full width and height of the container (which is why we set it to be `position: relative;`)

Doing this means that the `div` element is the size that the image will be, whether the image is loaded into it or not (the image itself has no bearing on the container size, since it is absolutely positioned)

Comment: Thanks this is really cool Blake. However there are a few issues with this. It shows broken image icons while the images load, (I'm using FF). Secondly, it's my fault for not mentioning that I have break points in which my images go down from 4 wide to 3 wide to 2 wide. So it's not necessary 3 wide indefinitely. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I used an `img` element just to suit your example, but I didn't actually put a valid image source, so that's why you see that. If you put it into practice for real, this won't be the case. In terms of breakpoints, just style the container `div` the same way you would have for your images, the aspect ratio will always remain correct, no matter what width you set the `div` to be.

Comment: Yeah for sure. I tried that code with proper image links but still seeing it. Maybe it was just my browser?

Comment: I've updated my demo to use real images: http://jsfiddle.net/serv0m8o/1/ . Do you see the same issue here? You definitely should not see broken image links at all

Comment: Yes it does, those placehold it images load instantly because they're super small size. I pasted in some image links that were larger and the broken box would appeared briefly while they loaded.